# ngrx effect() only triggers once - Angular 4

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have my login system built around ngrx/store. When I load up the site it works great the first time I submit the login credentials. But as soon as I do it twice (say I entered the password wrong) the event gets triggered but the effect does not. I cannot figure out what the problem is.

The @Effext() in question:

```
@Effect() loginUser$: Observable<any> = this.action
    .ofType(LOGIN)
    .map(toPayload)
    .flatMap(payload => this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login', payload))
    .map(data => ({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data.json()}))
    .catch(error => of({type: LOGIN_FAILED, payload: error}))
```

It is the same with all the Effect structured in this way.

[image]